# MVC3 C# + MSSQL case sensitive fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-validators

I have table in MSSQL server with field "Name nvarchar(10)"
Now I am trying to locate some data and I cant do case sensitive search.
i.e.

```
 this.SomeTable.SingleOrDefault(u => (u.Name==login));
```

or

```
 this.PortalUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => (u.Name.Equals(login))
```

returns a value, but should not, because "aaaa"!="AAAA"
How can it be fixed without modifying database cell collation?

Comment: Should I assume you're using Entity Framework as the ORM?

Comment: (that is, as your method of accessing the database?)  ORM just means Object Relational Mapping, which Entity Framework does, but it's not the only object relational mapper in existence.

Comment: I change collation inside MSSQL to case sensitive and it helped. But may be it is may be done without modification server side?

Comment: I see it is very old problem: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution, but if you can't change the MSSQL server, you are limited.

Try

```
 this.PortalUsers.Where(u => u.Name == login).ToList().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Name == login)
```

This will pull all the matching records regardless of case, convert it into an in memory array, and then pick out a single based on a case sensitive match.

I urge caution though, it isn't a great solution, it might return a signification number of records which have to be created in memory, nothing too expensive, but something to be wary of.

Si